# Convert each cell of a Pandas's column from list to word-count dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, counter

There's a column of a DataFrame, `df['Title']`, where each row is a book sold at a location, `LOCATION_ID`.  I'd like to group the `df` by `LOCATION_ID` and create a new DataFrame that has two columns: `LOCATION_ID` and a `Title-Count`dictionary of the books sold at each location.

Specifically, I'm trying to do something like:

```
from collections import Counter
new_df = df.groupby('LOCATION_ID')['TITLE'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x))
```

I'm expecting an output like:

```
LOCATION_ID  |     TITLES
1                 {'TitleA':12; 'TitleB':56 ; ...}
2                 {'TitleK':5; 'TitleC':23 ; ...}
...
```

But instead, I'm receiving one like:

```
LOCATION_ID                         Title                             
1               TitleA               12
                TitleB               56
...
2               TitleK              5
                TitleG              23
...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is wrong with your current output? It seems like, the output is what you want. Why do you need ther dictionaries?

Comment: TITLES will be feature in a logistic classifier.  The library method I'm going to use requires the dictionary format.

Comment: Are you going to use Scikit-learn?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input?

Comment: @Joe R I'm using graphlab's logistic_classifier.  I'd like to estimate:

    book_model = graphlab.logistic_classifier.create(train_data,
                                                     target='books_sold',
                                                     features=['book_count'],
                                                     validation_set=test_data)d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `agg` instead of `apply`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'LOCATION_ID': prng.choice([1, 2, 3], 1000), 'TITLE': [''.join(prng.choice(list("abcd"), 3)) for _ in range(1000)]})
df.head()
Out[9]: 
   LOCATION_ID TITLE
0            1   bbb
1            2   bab
2            1   daa
3            2   dcd
4            2   cbc
```

---

```
df.groupby('LOCATION_ID')['TITLE'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x)).head()
Out[10]: 
LOCATION_ID     
1            aaa    2.0
             aab    5.0
             aac    4.0
             aad    3.0
             aba    8.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df.groupby('LOCATION_ID')['TITLE'].agg(lambda x: Counter(x))
Out[11]: 
LOCATION_ID
1    {u'cbb': 5, u'cbc': 8, u'cba': 6, u'cda': 8, u...
2    {u'cdd': 5, u'cbc': 7, u'cbb': 1, u'cba': 4, u...
3    {u'cbb': 6, u'cbc': 7, u'cba': 4, u'cda': 6, u...
Name: TITLE, dtype: object
```

Your expectation makes sense. When you group items together, you'd expect pandas to return grouped results. However, `groupby.apply` is documented as [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply). Based on the returned object it infers how to combine the results. Here, it sees a dictionary and to offer you a better output it creates a multi-index series.